# What are the different ways to restore a database?

Tags: mysql, restore

From the most inoffensive of the cases, to the worst of the scenarios they know. What are the different ways to restore or recover a MySQL database? I refer to the use of full backups and incremental backups, among other ways to do it. I do not know if it can be done through ibdata and iblogfiles, is what I need to know ... Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are multiple ways to do backups.  Can't discuss recovery without knowing which back method was used.

Comment: @FrancoUgarte, What is MySQL version(x,y,z)?

Comment: MySQL version = 5.7, thanks @MdHaidarAliKhan

Comment: @RickJames A worst example scenario could be: a DBA that makes backup copies, but these were generated incorrectly or a virus deleted them. There was a fire and the place where the backups are stored was burned. And anyway, you need to recover a database, is it possible to do it with another method that is not backup?

Comment: My question is for preventive purposes, to know what to do in the future, based on your valuable experiences

Comment: Is it a "physical" backup, as in copying the disk drive?  Or a "logical" backup, as in creating the `CREATE` and `INSERT` SQL statements necessary to reload the data (see `mysqldump`)?  Well, you could do both.

Comment: @RickJames I appreciate your comment. My question has been made for prevention purposes, but more than that, with the purpose of knowing which strategy to use and knowing very well the risks that I am taking. Basically my question is Can the database be restored without backups, from the files that are left there (ib-logfile, ibdata), either a crashed database or a completely deleted database?

Comment: @FrancoUgarte - No.  Ibdata and iblog and binlog are not sufficient to recover anything.  For example, for a deleted database, you need full backup plus the binlogs since then.

Comment: @RickJames I appreciate your comment. Ok, I understand that there is no other way to recover a database either damaged, deleted, crashed, corrupted. Intentionally or unintentionally.

Comment: @FrancoUgarte - I was addressing one case.  If you have a power failure in the middle of a query, InnoDB is smart enough to recover, rollback that half-finished transaction, etc.  But that's a "normal" failure, not a "disaster recovery", such as losing the disk or the data center.

Comment: @RickJames Fully understood!
Have you heard the famous "journal of databases" ?. I've wanted to find something similar in MySQL, there's nothing like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backup and Recovery.  Also making a copy of a Database.

In order to "recover" a damaged database (aside from merely a power failure), you necessarily must have done some form of Backup.  So, here is an enumeration of backup+recovery techniques available to MySQL:

- Replication -- Continually keep a copy of the database on another server.  (Standard part of MySQL; but optionally deployed)
- Cluster technologies -- Enhancements on Replication.  (See Galera, Group Replication.)
- Delayed Replication -- This is where a Slave (usually only one of several Slaves) is kept "behind".  This, plus the binlog provide a way to "skip" the disastrous `DROP DATABASE` that someone accidentally (or deliberately) did.
- Binlog -- Part of an "incremental" backup plan.
- "Logical" dump -- capture `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements in order to recreate the database from SQL commands.  (See `mysqldump` and `mysql`)
- Other tools, such as Percona's XtraBackup.
- LVM -- Logical Volume Management -- This is a way to *very* efficiently copy the disk where the database lives.  (OS technique.)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario, disculpa el inglés, pero no es mi idioma natal. Aún así entendí las traducciones.

Comment: @FrancoUgarte - 'Three cheers for Google'; you said "Thank you very much for your comment, apology English, but not my native language. Yet I understood translations."

Comment: hahahaha que raro suena eso... Disculpas!

Answer (score 1):

Backup scenarios are designed around the risk profile. These include resilience and time to restore as the most critical factors.

The backup needs to account for the potential risks to be encountered including physical destruction, a malicious insider, a technological competent criminal, or a sever database flaw.

Backups will include offsite/offline backup based on risk assessment.

Backups can include a bunch of logical (SQL dumps), and binary backups (copy of the entire datadir based on stopped server or xtrabackup), binary logs for point in time recovery, and can frequently involve a replication slave to assist with such mechanisms.